# scroll up button appears when page loads

Tags: javascript

The process I'm using is supposed to make it so the "back to top" button doesn't appear. It works except for when you first load the page, the button exists. The second you scroll down, it disappears. When you scroll back to the top again, it doesn't appear. In other words, the button appears when you load the page, but after that, it works properly.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 500){
  $('#upButton:hidden').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
 } else {
  $('#upButton').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
 }
});
<div class="top" >
  <a href="#up" id="upButton" onclick="$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:
   $('#up').offset().top - 500}, 200);"> back to top<a/>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you hiding the button by default when the page loads?

Comment: No. How would I write that out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are hiding the button/link when the initially pages loads.  It is preferred to do it with CSS...

```
#upButton{
 display:none;
}
```

Or if you want to do with javascript you can do (I put it in a `document.ready` to emphasize that it would need to be done after the document loads)...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#upButton").hide();
});
```

Comment: It works in chrome, but it still shows up in firefox.

Comment: which are you doing?  CSS or JS?

Comment: I believe JS. I have a .CSS file though.

Comment: If you copied the JS version of my answer there was some typos.  I updated my answer fixing them.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but where would I place that code? is it just going to be in a script tag?

Comment: If you want to use the css then that would go into your css file.  The JS would be put in a JS file that is pulled into your page or you can put it in a script tag (as long as you have the `document.ready` wrapper to make sure that it runs after the document loads.